# Add 2 Arrays into Vector in specific order c++

Tags: c++, arrays, vector

Suppose I have 2 string arrays,

```
string firstName[John, Jane, Jason];
string middleName[L, M, N];
```

And a vector of strings,

```
vector<string> vec;
```

Is there a way to add these to the vector in a specific order so that each middle name is with each first name? So that when I print out the vector, it would print as:

John L

Jane M

Jason N

To add them to the vector I have:

```
    vector<string> vec;

    string firstName[] ={"John","Jane","Jason"};
    int N = sizeof(firstName)/ sizeof(firstName[0]);

    for(int i=0; i<N;i++)
        p.push_back(firstName[i]);

    string middleName[]={"L","M","N"};
    N = sizeof(middleName)/ sizeof(middleName[0]);

    for(int i=0; i<N;i++)
        p.push_back(middleName[i]);
```

But obviously that just prints in a single line "John Jane Jason L M N"

Comment: After ensuring they are the same size: `for (int i=0; i < N; i++) p.push_back(firstName[i] + " " + middleName[i]);`

Comment: *"obviously that just prints in a single line"* - not so obviously. that code doesn't print *anything*. Regardless, you need to enumerate *both* arrays in the *same* loop, picking from each to form the final composite of that pair, then push that composite into your result vector.

Comment: Unrelated: Instead of `int N = sizeof(firstName)/ sizeof(firstName[0]);` do `auto N = std::size(firstName);`

Comment: @JohnnyMopp You are my savior, thank you so much. That helps me out tremendously, I really appreciate your help!!!

Comment: @WhozCraig I had a separate line in my code using a for loop to print out the array, I just didn't feel like it was relevant to post it in order to keep the question as short as I could.

Comment: @TedLyngmo I will go ahead and change that now, thank you for your input, I really appreciate it!

Comment: @JohnnyMopp If you don't mind me asking, what would I do if I added in another array that had a last name for 1 of the people mentioned above, but not for the other 2? Since I cannot ensure that they will all be the same size?

Answer (score 0):

Couldn't add a comment due to reputation.
As Johnny Mopp's comment says, the answer is

> After ensuring they are the same size:
> `for (int i=0; i < N; i++) p.push_back(firstName[i] + " " + middleName[i]);`

To answer the last comment by OP:
You would of course need to know which person's surname it is. If there are n people and m(≤n) surnames, and you have the indices of those people who have surnames, then you just need to modify strings in the vector.
For example, if vector `p` (as above) has a size n, and you have an array `LastNamePositions` giving the positions of people with surnames, and `LastNames` stores the last names, then:

```
for (int i=0; i<LastNamePositions.size(); i++) {
    p[LastNamePositions[i]] = p[LastNamePositions[i]]+" "+LastNames[i];
}
```